# Making a pivot table in R

Tags: r

I have a table of data that looks similar like below:

```
Agent <- c("Dani","Dani","John","Peter","John","Dani","john")
Presentation <- c("A","B","C","A","B","A","B")

df1 <- data.frame(Agent, Presentation)
```

What I would like to have is something similar to a pivot table in Excel but it is in R. Which is something like below:

[image]

This will basically help me view the table like which agent did the A presentation the most and which agent did B presentation the most. I need to include this in my R report instead of Excel which is quite hard to do so. I am not even sure if it is even possible to do so. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Presentation, Agent) %>%
  summarize(n = n())
```

Comment: You can avoid `summarize(n = n())` by using `count`

Comment: Or simply: `dplyr::count(df1, Presentation, Agent)`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` to prepare this table -

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  count(Presentation, Agent = tools::toTitleCase(Agent)) %>%
  group_by(Presentation) %>%
  summarise(Agent = paste(Agent, n, sep = ':', collapse = ' ; '))

#  Presentation Agent           
#  <chr>        <chr>           
#1 A            Dani:2 ; Peter:1
#2 B            Dani:1 ; John:2 
#3 C            John:1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(n = .N), .(Presentation, Agent)]
```